# Json schema for object with generated keys

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a request of following format:

```
{
   "uuid_1": [{obj}, {obj}, {obj}],
   "uuid_2": [{obj}, {obj}],
   ...
   "uuid_n": [{obj}, {obj}],
}
```

obj is simple object which consist of a few ids, for example:

```
{
 id: string,
 userId: string,
}
```

I would like to keep this format of JSON, because change would require additional data processing on frontend and backend as well.

Note: uuids are generated, so I do not know in advance what uuids to expect.

So far I was able to specify, that keys of the object must be of **uuid format** with

> "propertyNames": {
> "format": "uuid"    }

How to define json schema for values of this object?
Thank you.

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@mplungjan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) comment about [Pattern properties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties),
I was able to compose following schema. (If it helps somebody).

```
{
    "type": 'object',
    "propertyNames": {
        "format": "uuid"
    },
    "patternProperties": {
        ".*": {
            "type": "array",
             "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ['id', 'userId'],
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "format": "uuid"
                    },
                    "userId": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "uuid"
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to use "additionalProperties": { ... } than "patternProperties": {".*": { ... }}